Databricks personal access token for different applications
I have question about databricks PAT.
I already have 1 PAT using for tableau. However, when I try to connect databricks data to power BI, the existing token did not work.
Do I need to create new token? When I create a token I can't specify which app I am going to use for that token, so it is confusing why I can't use the same token for differnt apps. How does databricks match token and each application?
Also, if I create a new token would it impact the existing tableu connection?
I tried connecting working power bi board with databricks table. I was able to get the table but could not set auto refresh. I tried using exisitng token used for tableau connection, but did not work.
